# How to replace if the NA values in any column that should replace values by the next column's values in R programming

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

1. How to replace if the NA values in any column that should replace values by the next column's values in R programming, This has to be done without particularly mentioned the name of the columns (without hardcode)
2. Also the entire column that had NA values should be removed in R programming

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- structure(list(GID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "NG1", "MG2", "MG3", "NG4"), 
                      ColA = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                      ColB = c("2", "4", "4", "5", "5", "", "1", "1", "")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
                 class = "data.frame")

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_replace(., "^$", "N")),
         GID = GID %>% str_remove("N"))
#>   GID ColA   ColB
#> 1   1    NA    2
#> 2   2    NA    4
#> 3   3    NA    4
#> 4   4    NA    5
#> 5   5    NA    5
#> 6  G1    NA    N
#> 7 MG2    NA    1
#> 8 MG3    NA    1
#> 9  G4    NA    N
```

**Expected output:**

```
#>   GID ColA   
#> 1   1    2
#> 2   2    4    
#> 3   3    4    
#> 4   4    5    
#> 5   5    5    
#> 6  G1    N   
#> 7 MG2    1    
#> 8 MG3    1    
#> 9  G4    N
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you already have answer to the first part of your question, here is an alternative way using `replace`. To drop columns that have all `NA` in them you can use `select` with `where`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(., . == '', 'N')), 
         GID = sub('N', '', GID)) %>%
  select(-where(~all(is.na(.)))) %>%
  rename_with(~names(df1)[seq_along(.)])

#  GID ColA
#1   1    2
#2   2    4
#3   3    4
#4   4    5
#5   5    5
#6  G1    N
#7 MG2    1
#8 MG3    1
#9  G4    N
```

Comment: it works perfectly, one small changes to be done. How to change only values not the column name.. I mean after replacing the values also the name of column "ColA" should be there (without hardcode any col names)